# adding KnownType for class in another Assembly

Tags: c#, wcf

I have class `B` that extends `A`, and because it is located in another assembly I cannot simply add `[KnownType(typeof(B))]` to `A` to get it to serialize because this requires a circular dependency. I tried doing this in the config but it doesn't work for some reason.

Now I am trying the method described here

[Generally accepted way to avoid KnownType attribute for every derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220242/generally-accepted-way-to-avoid-knowntype-attribute-for-every-derived-class/16223336)

(I load B's assembly instead of GetExecutingAssembly) When I try to update service references I get `The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved..."` What might be the problem here?

Comment: Provide the tried code .

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

Assume that **ClassA** is in assembly **A** and **ClassB** in assembly **B**, and **A** is referenced in **B**. Consider the following:

```
[KnownType("GetDerivedTypes")]
[DataContract]
public abstract class ClassA         \\This is referenced in B
{
    static Type[] GetDerivedTypes()
    { 
        return DerivedTypes.ToArray();  
    }
    public static List<Type> DerivedTypes = new List<Type>();
}
```

You cannot add typeof(ClassB) in the preceding. However,

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    static ClassB()
    {
        ClassA.DerivedTypes.Add(typeof(ClassB));
    }

    public ClassB()
    {
    }
}
```